# Uniqueness of some sort of QR decomposition

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-methods

Let $m \ge n, A=QR \in \mathbb C^{m \times n}$ with matrices $Q \in \mathbb C^{m \times m}, R \in \mathbb C^{m \times n}$ of the form

$$Q=\begin{pmatrix}Q_{11}&&Q_{12}\\Q_{21}&&Q_{22}\end{pmatrix}, R=\begin{pmatrix}R_1\\0\end{pmatrix}$$

and $Q_{11}, R_1 \in \mathbb C^{n \times n}, Q_{21} \in \mathbb C^{(m-n) \times n}, Q_{12} \in \mathbb C^{n \times (m-n)}, Q_{22} \in \mathbb C^{(m-n) \times (m-n)}$.

Furthermore let $Q$ be unitary and $R_1$ and upper triangular matrix with positive diagonal elements.

> Show that $R_1, Q_{11}, Q_{21}$ are uniquely defined these assumptions.

We can write $A=Q_1R_1$ with $Q_1=\begin{pmatrix}Q_{11}\\Q_{21}\end{pmatrix}$.

Assume there are matrices $q_1,r_1$ such that $A=q_1r_1$. (I want to show that $Q_1=q_1$ and $R_1=r_1$ then we should be finished.)

Then we have $Q_1R_1=q_1r_1$.

Somehow we will have to use the fact that $R_1$ is invertible. But I don't really know how to tackle this problem

Answer (score 1):

Consider
$$
Q_1^\dagger q_1=R_1r_1^{-1}
$$
The left side is unitary, as both matrices span the same sub-space, the column space of $A$. The right side is upper triangular. What unitary upper triangular matrices do exist with positive real diagonals?

Comment: The identity matrix, if I am not missing out on something.

Comment: Exactly. Which proves the desired identities.

Comment: So because this is equal to the identity matrix, and the inverse of an invertible matrix is unique, we know that $R_1=r_1$ and $q_1=Q_1$. Right?

Comment: One has to make an extra argument that the left side is unitary, isometric maps with the same range should be sufficient. A more detailed argument would start with $q_1=Q_1\,R_1r_1^{-1}$ and consider the columns from back to front. The last column of $q_1$ is a positive multiple of the last column of $Q_1$, both have length $1$, thus they have to be the same. This makes the last column of $R_1r_1^{-1}$ zero up to the diagonal entry. Now the situation reduced by the last column has the same properties as the full case,...

Comment: Can you explain that part  "both have length $1$, thus they have to be the same. This makes the last column of $R_1r_1^{-1}$ zero up to the diagonal entry". I don't even know what you mean by "both have length $1$". Then you use the same argument for the matrix reduced by last column and so on I think... And then finally, how does this show that the left hand side is unitary?

Comment: If you have two vectors $u,v$ with $u=rv$ and $r>0$, and you also know that $\|u\|=\|v\|$, then immediately $r=1$ follows. Now the entries of the columns of $R_1r_1^{−1}$ are coefficients of unit vectors in another orthonormal system, so their square sum (of absolute values) is always smaller than $1$. With the above observation, this budget for the last column is used up with the last entry of it, so the other entries have to be zero.